# Ассемблер, не работает команда

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

Скачал я значит emu8086, хорошая программка для изучения ассемблера

Написал код:

```
MAKE_COM        ; инструкция компилятора для создания СОМ-файла.
ORG    100h
MOV AX, 3Ah
MOV CX, [AX]; Здесь ругается не понимаю, почему?
RET
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему ничего не записывает в регистр CX?

Comment: Неужели, все бессильны?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке не надо приводить, да? Ну и рискну предположить что нужно указать сегментный регистр...

Comment: оу забыл, сейчас прикреплю

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке должно быть ПОЛНЫМ и в виде ТЕКСТА, а не картинки. И еще обратите внимание на само сообщение и на то, что только в одной строке у вас ';' в конце.

Comment: это не ошибка, похоже вы даже не учили ассемблер, раз не знаете что ; - для комментариев, что априори не может являться ошибкой

Comment: Что вам непонятно в моем вопросе? Вроде бы все кристально понятно что причина в строке MOV но почему программа не компилирует код неясно

Comment: Вам, я вижу, тоже непонятно что вам пишут. Ну удачи...

Comment: вы такой странный, лезете в ассемблер ничего не зная, смысл было вообще мне что-то писать, если вы по делу 0. Если вы знаете как решить приведите код, иначе это все пустословие

Comment: Текст сообщения об ошибке все еще не полный и в виде картинки это раз. Про сегментный регистр вам было написано сразу - это два. И да, FASM, похоже хочет мнемоники и имена регистров в НИЖНЕМ регистре, это три. А в ассемблере не понимаете вы, раз вопросы задаете.

Comment: ассемблер не чувствителен  к регистру, и да я пробовал писать в разных регистрах результат один - ОШИБКА
Что по поводу сегментого регистра? Зачем он мне? Вы видите какую команду я написал? Поместить в регистр CX значение значение (размера byte) из памяти указанной в AX (3Ah) 
P.S Минусовать пост - о как это низко из-за того что у вас пригорело от меня
P.S А разве все хорошо шарят в ассемблере? Если да то почему мне до сих пор не накидали ответов?

Comment: Заминусовали вопрос за то, что сообщение об ошибке неполное и не текстом и вот как припекло-то! Кстати, mov bx, 3ah, mov cx, [bx] тоже не работает?

Comment: хм ранее так же пробовал, не работало, а сейчас пашет...странно в чем дело?

Comment: А я вам, как не разбирающийся в асме скажу: не все регистры можно использовать для косвенной адресации. (E)BX допустим, (E)AX - нет.

Comment: Я просто такую команду видел на одном сайте, только регистры были 32битные

Comment: Хм-хм, кажись я наврал: EAX допустим, по крайней мере софтина с mov     edx, [eax] точно пашет.

Comment: в этом эмуляторе максимально 16 бит регистр

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не все 16-битные регистры могут быть использованы для косвенной адресации. А именно, в вашем случае в квадратных скобках могут быть использованы только регистры bp, bx, si, di. 32-битный регистр сюда подойдет любой (если, конечно, у вас достаточно новый процессор).

Больше про режимы адресации с упором на DOS можно почитать здесь: [fasmworld.ru: Учебный курс. Часть 14. Режимы адресации](https://fasmworld.ru/uchebnyj-kurs/014-rezhimy-adresacii/)

Кстати, emu8086 имеет довольно опосредственное отношение к fasm. fasm на код аналогичный вашему выдает другую ошибку:

```
flat assembler  version 1.71.22  (1048576 kilobytes memory)
test.asm [5]:
mov cx, [ax]
error: reserved word used as symbol.
```